# Array Push to Array of Objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, array-push

I have an array in this format;

```
// echo '<pre>' . var_export($this->viewableFields, true) . '</pre>';

array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'formId' => '4',
     'componentId' => '-7',
     'viewable' => '1',
     'searchable' => '0',
     'editable' => '0'
  ),
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'formId' => '4',
     'componentId' => '-4',
     'viewable' => '1',
     'searchable' => '1',
     'editable' => '0'
  )
)
```

I am selecting some data from a mysql database and I need to add this to the array. I want to add `group = Registered`, so the output will look like this;

```
// echo '<pre>' . var_export($this->viewableFields, true) . '</pre>';

array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'formId' => '4',
     'componentId' => '-7',
     'viewable' => '1',
     'searchable' => '0',
     'editable' => '0',
     'group' => 'Registered'
  ),
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'formId' => '4',
     'componentId' => '-4',
     'viewable' => '1',
     'searchable' => '1',
     'editable' => '0',
     'group' => 'Registered'
  )
)
```

I have tried the following but it simply creates another item at the end of the array (number [2]).

```
$group = (object) array(
    'group' => 'Registered'
);

array_push($this->viewableFields, $group);
```

Note, I can't modify the SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$this->viewableFields` is your wider array, you can use `array_walk()` to modify the array in-situ.

```
array_walk($this->viewableFields, function(&$arr) {
    $arr->group = 'Registered';
});
```